# understanding basics of arguments in javascript

Tags: javascript

hey guys i am very new to java scripts but have read a few beginner books on js and i was going through the MDN doc's to understand how [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) works in js and came across the following script :

```
    function list(type) {
      var result = "<" + type + "l><li>";
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
      result += args.join("</li><li>");
      result += "</li></" + type + "l>"; // end list

      return result;
    }

    var listHTML = list("u", "One", "Two", "Three");

console.log(listHTML);  // "<ul><li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li></ul>"
```

have a close look at what gets printed out .

now this works quite counter intuitive to how i expected it to work .

so lets break it down , suppose i call the function list like below :

```
list("u", "One", "Two", "Three");
```

now what happens in the list function is

```
  var result = "<" + type + "l><li>"; // here type is still --  "u", "One", "Two", "Three" , than why does only u get inserted ?? 
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1); // in understand this line 
  result += args.join("</li><li>");
  result += "</li></" + type + "l>"; // end list

  return result;
```

for this programme to work as i figured out , it is critical that on the 1st line only "u" get inserted and not all the arguments (see my comment) , but how is this being done in this snippet , i know it a simple snippet of code , but i am really sitting here , scratching my head looking at this code.

can somebody explain ?

**EDIT** my expected output is :

```
<uOneTwoThreel><li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li></uOneTwoThreel>
```

Thanks .

Alex-z

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: `type` is not "u", "One", "Two", "Three" - it's only "u". if you have `function fn(arg1, arg2) { // body }` and you call it as `fn("foo", "bar", "baz")`, `arg1` will be `"foo"`, `arg2` will be `"baz"`, and the third parameter will not have a variable created for it, but will feature in `arguments`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Javascript the pseudo-array `arguments` contains **everything** that has been passed to the function, while the named arguments listed in the function argument list get filled with the passed value ignoring extra arguments and setting `undefined` if not enough argument have been passed.

For example calling `function f(x, y){...}` with `f(1,2,3,4)` will have

- `x` = 1
- `y` = 2
- `arguments` = `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

and instead calling `function g(x, y){...}` with `g(1)` will have

- `x` = 1
- `y` = `undefined`
- `arguments` = `[1]`

Note that `arguments` is not an array, and therefore you cannot use all array methods (like `join`). This is the reason for which the `slice` trick is used to convert all arguments skipping the first one in an array.

Answer (score 2):

the problem here is `type` is a argument which will hold the value of 1 first parameter to the method call, in your case `u`. Since you don't have as many arguments as the passed parameters rest of the params will not have a formal reference.

```
function list() {
    //this will create an array params which will have all the values of the arguments object
    var params = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);

    //we joins all the passes params to create the type
    var type = params.join('');
    var result = "<" + type + "l><li>";

    //we ignores the first parameter here
    var args = params.slice(1);
    result += args.join("</li><li>");
    result += "</li></" + type + "l>";

    return result;
}

var listHTML = list("u", "One", "Two", "Three");

console.log(listHTML);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w3zgkd0f/)